# Dokku identifies rails application as node application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

I'm new to Dokku, and got a mature Heroku project running for 3 years, I got this annoying issue that Dokku thinks my rails app is a node app probably because I got the package.json file that I use for client side tests.  What should I do (currently I renamed this file to trick Dokku but this is kind of hacky) to tell Dokku I have a rails app? What is the proper buildpack I should specify and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a custom buildpack as noted [here](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/buildpacks/#specifying-a-custom-buildpack).

For your application, you'll probably want to use the [ruby buildpack](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/buildpacks/#specifying-a-custom-buildpack).